# Conversion Failed String to Integer in SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, msbi

I have stored the OrganisationIds 1 ,2 in @String variables.i want to convert it into Integer.Can anyone please help?

Below is my code..

```
DECLARE @RowCount INT
Declare @String varchar(100)
declare @OrganizationIds int
SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*) FROM @RawData
WHILE (@RowCount>0)
BEGIN
       set @String=convert(varchar,@OrganizationIds)+','
         If (@RowCount>0)
         Begin  

            PRINT 'Loop Sequence : ' + convert(varchar,@RowCount)  + ' '
                        set  @OrganizationIds = (SELECT  OrgId FROM @RawData WHERE ROWID = @RowCount)
            PRINT 'Orgid Inside Loop:' +  Convert(varchar,@OrganizationIds)

End
   Set @RowCount = @RowCount-1
 Set  @OrganizationIds =  convert(varchar,@OrganizationIds) 
PRINT 'Orgid Outside Loop:'+   convert(varchar,@OrganizationIds)
set @String=@String + Convert(varchar,@OrganizationIds) 
END
PRINT 'String Value Outside Loop: ' + @String
Declare  @TempData Table
(
    OrganizationID int
)
insert into @TempData(OrganizationID)
EXEC GetFormsData_Organization @String
```

Comment: You need to show how your varaiables look like are they stored as seperate strings or comma seperated

Comment: My variables are looks like this  '1','2','3' comma separated

Comment: @TheGameiswar Looks like both.

Comment: Yes..Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use the CAST function instead of convert. Try if that solves the problem.